# Wordpress - Migrate 404s to different domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

Backstory, I've got a "php/symfony web app" that is currently hosted on `www.example.com` but I'm wanting to have that whole functionality be moved to `app.example.com` so I can spin up a wordpress site that handles all of the `www` traffic (its our marketing pages).

The challenge/issue is that we have links in the wild referencing `www` (ex `www.example.com/thing/handled/by/app`).  So I need to find a wordpress plugin that will issue 301's for anything it doesn't know how to handle (aka wp needs to have 404 redirect to `app`).

So if we create a `/pricing` page in the wordpress site, then its available at `www.example.com/pricing` and handled by wordpress.  But if someone goes to `www.example.com/foo` which is not a page wordpress is able to handle, then we have a 301 to `app.example.com/foo`.  I'm finding some plugins that handle "known" routes but I basically need to have a wildcard redirect but for 404's only.

Let me know if additional details are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). It has a 404 log, and also supports 301 redirects using specified links or regular expression matching.

**Edit** having re-read your requirements, you should be able to just add the following snippet to your theme's functions.php file.

This will intercept the WordPress lifecycle after a query has been resolved, but before a template is rendered. If the request is not for a page in the admin panel and it is resolved to a 404, then it will redirect the request to your app instead.

```
add_action('template_redirect', function () {
    if (! is_admin() && is_404()) {
        header('Location: https://app.example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my first plugin eval.  But I didn't see way to take action solely on 404s (yes, they log but I need to redirect there).

Comment: @jsuggs - I've added a code snippet that should do what you need.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @fubar but worked like a charm.  Thanks!